# Python: binary digits

Tags: list, python-3.x, binary

I have a two-digit number (`42` for example) and i have to get a list of bits for every digit like this

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO: You are encouraged to provide code that you have tried so far to overcome any problems you have encountered. If you haven't yet written any code, perhaps you should google your problem domain. [Here](http://interactivepython.org/courselib/static/pythonds/BasicDS/ConvertingDecimalNumberstoBinaryNumbers.html) is one example site that describes how to tackle your problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
def bin(s):
   return str(s) if s<=1 else bin(s>>1) + str(s&1)
```

it's function for one digit, if you have multiple digits, do it for x % 10 and then divide your number by 10 for every digit

Comment: I can also do `map(bin, list(str(number)))` where `bin` is your function